# CommitDeniedException Spark : how to resolve this?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, commit, emr, parquet

I am getting :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to commit task
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.commitTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:267)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.executor.CommitDeniedException: attempt_201611091630_0009_m_000131_1: Not committed because the driver did not authorize commit
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitTask(WriterContainer.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.commitTask$1(WriterContainer.scala:282)
    ... 9 more
```

while using write.parquet. Is there any way I can resolve this ? I am using Spark 1.5.

Comment: have you found a solution ?